# iPhoneにて、自アプリのアンインストールを検知する方法はありますか？

Tags: swift, android, iphone

AndroidはBroadcastで通知されるパッケージ削除Intentを受信することで可能との情報を見ました。
iPhoneの場合で、自アプリのアンインストールを検知する方法があれば、教えてほしいです。

【やりたいこととして】
ユーザーがスマホアプリをアンインストールした時にメルマガ配信通知を停止するWebAPIを実行したい。
(通信不可環境ではいたしかたなし）

Answer (score 4):

アンインストールを検知する手段はありますが、限定的で、Androidのように各デバイスで動作しているアプリがアンインストールをトリガーに動くことができるようなものではありません。またリアルタイムでもありません。アンインストールされておよそ１週間ほど経ってから知ることができます。

アプリがPush通知を有効にしている場合、Apple Push Notification Feedback Serviceを通じて、Push通知が届かなかったデバイストークンを知ることができます。
それを使ってアプリケーションがアンインストールされた（あるいは機種変更なども含まれる）ことを検知します。

なのでやりたいことを実現するにはデバイストークンとユーザーを関連させてわかるようにしておく必要もあります。

多少簡単な方法としては広告SDK等が提供するトラッキングの仕組みを利用することです。

広告SDKも同様にAPNS Feedback Serviceを利用してアンインストールを検知していますが、自分でそこを実装する必要がないためより簡単に利用できます。

例えば下記はAdjustという広告SDKが提供するアンインストール計測のドキュメントです。

同様にいくつかの広告・トラッキングSDKを調べてみると良いでしょう。

> アンインストールと再インストールの計測
> https://ja.help.adjust.com/tracking/uninstalls-reinstalls#track-uninstalls-and-reinstalls-on-ios